# Android 2.3 + Phonegap fixed positioning is not working

Tags: android, cordova

On my Phonegap app i'm trying to make out a fixed footer and header, that actually in Android 4.0 works great. But on Android 2.3 even if it looks okay, when I start to scroll the header and footer doesen't stay fixed at all, going along with the scrolling.

The relevant code follows below:

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid no-padding">
<div id="header">

</div>  
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="main-content"></div>
    <div id="push"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer" class="main-footer">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,body,.container-fluid {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Helvetica !important;
}

#wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: -20px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
    overflow: scroll;
}

#footer, #push {
    height: 20px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
    width: 100%;
}

#footer {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10; /* Defect #9 */
    margin: 0;
    bottom:0px;
}

#header {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 5;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px !important;
}

#main-content {
    margin-top: 45px;
}

.main-footer {
    background-color: #cf2129;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

If it is relevant, I'm not using jQuery Mobile (that most part of the awnsers I found relate to), but Twitter Bootstrap instead.

Any guidance is welcome

Comment: I am having a similar problem currently - namely with android 4.2 and phonegap 2.7. I think i'll add some code later

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found it out,

Just add "user-scalable=0" to the meta viewport tag.

> Web designers are used to fixing elements to the window using CSS’s position: fixed, however, in the land of mobile browsers, support for fixed positioning is far less universal and is way more quirky.

Source: http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/

It tells everything you need to know about fixed elements and mobile browsers :)

Comment: Not exactly the best solution, though, since you are trading one piece of functionality for another. Now the user can't scale any of the content in your site on mobile devices. Does someone else have a scalable solution to this issue?

Comment: Since I want to transmit a native app look and feel actually the user is not supposed to scale :) But I get your point... maybe use a JS hack?

Answer (score 2):

I *seem* to have found a simple fix for Android 2.2 and 2.3. Just add:

`-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to the element you are using fixed positioning on.

More details about that here: http://benfrain.com/easy-css-fix-fixed-positioning-android-2-2-2-3/

Not tested it exhaustively so let me know if it doesn't work for you. Live URL to test here: http://codepen.io/benfrain/full/wckpb

Answer (score 0):

This are kind of issues i am having when i was developing a PhoneGap Application.Sometimes its phonegap version is not compitable with the android version.So its create issues but i have faced similar kind of issue in past.What i have done instead of giving id to div use class. like

```
<div class="header">
</div>
```

and for css use class instead of id.

```
.header
{
   position:fixed;
}
```

I know it seems very odd,funny answer.Not worthing at all. but this work for me.That's why i am sharing with you.